Graph API IAuthenticationProvider removed
I had an application using Graph API in Java that required an IAuthenticationProvider in order to build the GraphClient.
GraphServiceClient<Request> client = authService
            .graphClient(authService.getAuthProvider(authGraphProviderRequest));

My GraphClient is implemented in the service layer:
@Override
public GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient(IAuthenticationProvider iAuthenticationProvider) {
    return GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(iAuthenticationProvider)
            .buildClient();
}

To retrieve the authProvider, I call getAuthProvider, and this method requires an AuthGraphProviderRequest object:
@Builder
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AuthGraphProviderRequest {
    private String tenantClientId;
    private String tenantClientSecret;
    private String tenantApplicationId;
    private String tenantAuthority;
    private String scope;
    private String token;
}

This class can either send token OR the clientId, clientSecret, applicationId and scope to get an Authentication provider.
@Override
public IAuthenticationProvider getAuthProvider(AuthGraphProviderRequest authGraphProviderRequest) throws Exception {
    if (authGraphProviderRequest.getToken() == null)
        authGraphProvider.setToken(authenticate(authGraphProvider).accessToken());
    return requestUrl -> {
        CompletableFuture<String> authProvider = new CompletableFuture<>();
        authProvider.complete(authGraphProvider.getToken());
        return authProvider;
    };
}

For this implementation I was using the following dependencies:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.18</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.8</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>5.57.0</version>
</dependency>

I have to update the following dependencies with:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.17</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/msal4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
   <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
   <version>6.14.0</version>
</dependency>

Apparently, IAuthenticationProvider has been removed and replaced with AuthenticationProvider, which is implemented by BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider, for example.
My issue is that I don't find how I can retrieve the Provider for my client.

I wanted to use token because i thought it wasn't cached. Actually, I just needed to get a ClientCredential and instantiate directly the client. There were no need to use IAuthenticationProvider.
@Override
public GraphServiceClient graphClient(
        AuthGraphProviderRequest  authGraphProviderRequest) {
    ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = clientSecretCredential(authGraphProviderRequest);
    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    if(authGraphProviderRequest.getScope() == null)
        scopes.add(SharepointConstants.SCOPE_MS_GRAPH_DEFAULT);
    else
        scopes.add(authGraphProviderRequest.getScope());
    return graphClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes.toArray(String[]::new));
}


@Override
public GraphServiceClient graphClient(
        ClientSecretCredential  clientSecretCredential,
        String[] scopes) {
    return new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
}

@Override
public ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential(
        AuthGraphProviderRequest authGraphProviderRequest) {
    return new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(authGraphProviderRequest.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(authGraphProviderRequest.getClientSecret())
            .tenantId(authGraphProviderRequest.getTenantId())
            .build();
}

